# Ошибка "Cannot use import statement outside a module" при использовании import в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import {parse} from 'himalaya'
var request = require('request');
request('https://gdz.ru/class-1/matematika/moro-m-i-2011/1-4-3/', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', parse(body)); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Здравствуйте. Просто простейший код, но я не понимаю из-за чего вылезает ошибка.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Вы используете этот код в браузере или как скрипт для Node.js?

Comment: Как скрипт. Отдельный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, импорты еще в экспериментальном режиме, запускайте исполнение файла из флажком

`--experimental-modules`

Хотя и с этим флажком могут быть проблемы, лучше всего поставить esm

`npm install --save esm`

И запускать уже из под него

`node -r esm app.js`

Comment: Я сослался на ваш ответ, закрывая вопрос в качестве дубликата, по этому хочу попросить вам добавить в ваш ответ ещё один вариант решения проблемы: использование `require` вместо `import`