# как экспортировать const

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

У меня есть два файла и нужно экспортировать const из одного в другой.Сама не понимаю почему неверно.
Пишу вот так `import route from './routes/auth'`

Файл откуда экспорт

```
const express = require('express')

import * as AuthController from '../controllres/auth'

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/signup', AuthController.signup)
router.post('/signin', AuthController.signin)

export default router;
```

Файл куда экспорт

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const session = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const config = require('config')
const bluebird = require('bluebird')

import route from './routes/auth'

const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000

const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = bluebird


mongoose.connect(config.get('database'))
            .then( () => console.log('mongoOk'))
            .catch( () => console.log('nook'))


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`port ${PORT}`))

app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "steind"
}))

app.use('/api', route)
```

Comment: Неверно, потому что в node.js для импортов используется `required()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка "Cannot use import statement outside a module" при использовании import в node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071063/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-import-%d0%b2)

Comment: Вместо `import route from './routes/auth'` попробуйте написать `const route = require('./routes/auth');`

Answer (score 1):

`export` и `import` в `NodeJS` все еще находятся в экспериментальном режиме. Вы можете их использовать указав параметр `"type": "module"` в вашем `package.json` файле. Применяя данный подход, вы также должны явно указать расширение файла, которое импортируете.

Подробнее об этом можно посмотреть здесь:

- [Определение модульной системы](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system)
- [package.json и расширения файлов](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_package_json_and_file_extensions)

Также обратите внимание на слово `controllres` у вас там опечатка.

И еще один нюанс: `app.listen()` лучше вызывать в самом конце, после добавления всех `app.use()` и подобных конструкций, потому как объект `app` подвергается изменениям и ему нужно собрать всю необходимую информацию до того как приложение будет готово и переведено в режим прослушивания.

Я использую версию `NodeJS` `14.15.1` и вот что у меня получилось:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**controllers/auth.js**

```js
export function signup(req, res, next) {
  return res.end('signup', 'utf8');
}

export function signin(req, res, next) {
  return res.end('signin', 'utf8');
}
```

**routes/auth.js**

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

import * as AuthController from '../controllers/auth.js';

const router = Router();
router.get('/signup', AuthController.signup);
router.get('/signin', AuthController.signin);

export default router;
```

**index.js**

```js
import express from 'express';
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser';

import route from './routes/auth.js';

const PORT = 5000;
const app = express();

app.use('/api', route);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: `import` есть в JavaScript - https://learn.javascript.ru/import-export#import

Comment: Хм, да действительно. Я могу ошибаться, возможно он находится на экспериментальной стадии, во всяком случае [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) сказано что только начинает поддерживаться. С [нодой](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field) может быть то же самое. Тогда возможно [это поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module#answer-59399717)?!

Comment: Он достаточно давно используется, особенно часто вместе с webpack

Comment: Скорее проблема в том, что в node js для импорта используется `require()`

Comment: @Voprositel в node.js можно использовать import/export, если в package.json "type"="module", либо испльзуется расширение .mjs. Но соглашусь, мешать require и import нельзя и странно, что это не приводит к ошибке.